# Не отправляется post запрос (cross domain) из vuejs(axios) в laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, cors

На сайте с формой установлен vuejs, axios они лежат на домене: [https://домен1.ру](https://xn--1-gtbd1agd.xn--p1ag)
Laravel развернут на IIS с доменом: [https://домен2.ру](https://xn--2-gtbd1agd.xn--p1ag), доступ к api осуществляется через Passport, все контроллеры созданы, через POSTMAN запросы уходят без всяких ошибок.

Но стоит мне отправить форму с [https://домен1.ру](https://xn--1-gtbd1agd.xn--p1ag) на [https://домен2.ру/api/createOrder](https://xn--2-gtbd1agd.xn--p1ag/api/createOrder) то на сайте с формой падает ошибка
**"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://домен2.ру/api/createOrder' from origin 'https://домен1.ру' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."**

перерыл весь гугл и яндекс ничего толкового, что могло бы решить мою проблему не нашел. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Вот код метода в vue.js для формы

```
formSubmit(e) {
            var payload = {
                id_service: this.servicesModel,
                object_type: this.typeObjModel,
                object_address: this.address,
                object_area: this.areaStr,
                branch_id: this.branchModel,
                order_name: this.orderName,
                order_phone: this.orderPhone,
                order_email: this.orderMail,
                comments: this.comments
            };
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentObj = this;
            axios.post('https://домен2.ру/api/createOrder',
            payload,{
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'WithCredentials': true,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': ''
                },
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: 'same-origin',
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                currentObj.output = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                currentObj.output = error;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Запросы с других доменов должны быть разрешены на серверной стороне, смотри на бэкенде настройки CORS.

Comment: на стороне IIS разрешил CORS, все равно выпадает ошибка. Сейчас пробую установить пакет CORS на Laravel, надеюсь этот шаг поможет

Comment: Не помогло, попробовал сервис https://reqbin.com для POST запроса. Там никаких ошибок не возникло, POSTMAN тоже без ошибок, но с моего же сайта возникает проблема, я уже не знаю куда копать...

Comment: Postman - не показатель, т.к. не из браузера запрос. Сравните два запроса по заголовкам с regbin и с вашего фронта.